# ¿Cómo hacer un estilo de borde cortado diagonalmente a un div?

Tags: css

Hola amigos quisiera que me ayuden, quiero darle un estilo a un div con un borde cortado que contiene un texto, tipo google, estoy intentando pero no puedo.
Les dejo el link para que vean,. es una encuesta online de google: http://goo.gl/forms/7cQEZDxNAo

Adjunto una imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Preguntan como se anadio un estilo para un div? En eso caso asi:
<div style="margin-top: 5px"></div>

Comment: Podrias ver el código fuente del link que nos has pasado y ver tu mismo como lo han hecho. pero te adelanto que no usan CSS para eso sino que hacen la esquina del triangulo con un svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas la developer tools del browser, a la cual accedes con F12, puedes inspeccionar el html.

De esta forma podrias analiza el uso de los tag `svg` y `polygon`

```css
.freebirdMaterialHeaderbannerSectionTriangleContainer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 18px;
}


.freebirdSolidFill {
    fill: #DB4437;
    stroke: #DB4437;
}
```

```html
<div class="freebirdMaterialHeaderbannerSectionTriangleContainer">

   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="freebirdMaterialHeaderbannerSectionTriangle"> 
  
        <polygon class="freebirdSolidFill" points="0,0 10,0 0,10"></polygon>
  
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias estimado Leandro, ya logré solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Carlos en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7241/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-estilo-de-borde-cortado-diagonalmente-a-un-div#comment13146_7241), si miras el código podrás ver que lo consiguen usando SVG con un polygon (copiado del enlace que compartes):

```css
.freebirdMaterialHeaderbannerSectionTriangle>polygon {
    stroke-width: 1;
}
.freebirdSolidFill {
    fill: rgb(219, 68, 55);
    stroke: rgb(219, 68, 55);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="freebirdMaterialHeaderbannerSectionTriangle">
  <polygon class="freebirdSolidFill" points="0,0 10,0 0,10"></polygon>
</svg>
```

La imagen se adapta a la altura del contenedor y e ve bien entonces.

Si quieres hacerlo exclusivamente con CSS y sin SVG (como está etiquetada la pregunta), podrías hacerlo utilizando los bordes (aunque esta solución es un poco *hacky* y no siempre se verá bien porque no permite mucha configuración):

```css
div {
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

div:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:-30px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #f00;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div>Título de la Sección</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro, me sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez llegue muy tarde a responder, tal vez ya sabes como hacerlo, pero bueno, creo que le puede servir a alguien. Va para quienes no saben y buscan como hacerlo fácilmente.

Para hacer un div cortado de esa manera solo hace falta algo como esto:

```css
#DivCortado{
   border-bottom: 40px solid transparent; /*Los 40px modifican lo alto.*/
   border-left: 16px solid red; /*Los 16px modifican lo ancho del triangulo y red obviamente sera el color que tendrá.*/
}
```

```html
<div id="DivCortado"> </div>
```

Un div normal rectangular de toda la vida con el texto y aun lado el divCortado.